# Multiple JS Engine Helpers cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I have two plugins that both need to extend the JqueryEngineHelper.

I know that you can only specify one engine in AppController Helpers.

How can I extend the JqueryEngineHelper in both plugins? I have them both working but I cannot get them to work at the same time.

```
$helpers = ['Js'=>['MyPlugin.MyPluginJquery', 'MyPlugin2.MyPlugin2Jquery']];
```

I would like both to work, but unfortunately they do not. Only the first one is used.

**Code from one of the engines**

```
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');
App::uses('JqueryEngineHelper', 'View/Helper');

class MrgCustomSelectJqueryEngineHelper extends JqueryEngineHelper{

    function __construct(View $view, $settings = array()){
        parent::__construct($view, $settings = array());

        $this->_init_callbacks();
    }

    protected function _init_callbacks(){
        $callbacks = [
            'selectBoxIt'=>[]
        ];
        $this->_callbackArguments = array_merge($this->_callbackArguments, $callbacks);
    }


    public function selectBoxIt($options = []){
        $template = '%s.selectBoxIt({%s});';
        return $this->_methodTemplate('selectBoxIt', $template, $options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have to alter the plugins so that they don't conflict.  Depending on how the plugins work, there may be different ways you can go about this:

1. Only load the version Js helper you need at the moment.  Only works if you don't need both for a single controller action.
2. Change the plugins to refer to the different versions of Js helper by different names.  This could possibly take a lot of search and replace.
3. If there are no conflicts between how the plugins extended Js helper, you can merge the two helpers.

Comment: I think 1 and 3 are possibilities. How can I merge the two but keep the plugins independant?

Comment: I would either remove the js helper from both of them and put the merged version in the main application, or if you need to keep the js helper with the plugin, put the merged version in both plugins, but only bother loading one of them in your app.